# MySQL table collation suddenly changed to "in use"

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I went to connect to my website via firefox earlier this afternoon and I got an error message reading "Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'." This is particularly weird because I haven't touched the DB at all during the past few days and my site was working just fine up until a few hours ago. When I went to phpmyadmin, I noticed that some of the tables that had the collations utff8_general_ci have been changed to "in_use" and their engines have been changed from MyISAM to nothing... the engine type is just left blank in phpmyadmin. I'm kind of new to the more intricate aspects of mysql and don't know what's going on. Could someone offer some insight that could possibly lead me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Lance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

```
REPAIR TABLE `table_name`
```

Comment: didn't work, got Table 'dev_phi.phidiagnosisimportdatum' doesn't exist in engine

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a table, but a view that references another table/view that doesn't exist anymore.  If this is the case, when you click on the table name, then an error will appear:

## 1356 - View 'PervAtOtherData' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them

To view what the view is calling use this SQL:

```
SHOW CREATE VIEW `PervAtOtherData`;
```

Or, to delete the view:

```
DROP VIEW `PervAtOtherData`;
```

Answer (score 0):

If on windows, do system restore. I had the same problem on 37 tables. It worked for me. If hosted replace the database tables with the ones you have on your computer