# Xampp table goes into in_use collation

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have a xampp database, where 1 particular table is going into "in_use" collation everyday when I start the system. When I try to query the table or open it in phpmyadmin, I get #1932 "Table does not exist in Engine" error.

Notably, only one table (same table) is giving this issue every day.

Any ideas to what might be causing this?

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/11245316/5193536

Comment: Though it doesn't help(I have been running multiple such commands in an effort to resolve this and have now been able to figure out what is working for me yet), what I am looking for is why it is happening everyday and how to stop this from happening

Comment: usually you have a problem with your harddrive, but you could always look when that haoens in the mysql error log to see if there indications for another problem